# Socket program blocks on multiple read/write requests

Tags: c, sockets

I'm writing a program to examine the potential throughput of traditional TCP/IP using sockets in C. For now, the data content being transmitted between the client and server for now is irrelevant. The only thing that matters is that the data is transmitted successfully. The client is suppose to request a large amount, say 10,000, pairs of read/write operations from/to server. I'm running into some blocking issues, where both the client and the server stalls after the first few operations.

**client.c**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    int sockfd,n;
    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;

    sockfd=socket(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,0);
    bzero(&servaddr,sizeof servaddr);

    servaddr.sin_family=AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_port=htons(8080);

    inet_pton(AF_INET,"192.168.0.3", &(servaddr.sin_addr));
    connect(sockfd,(struct sockaddr *)&servaddr,sizeof(servaddr));

    char sendline[100];
    char recvline[100];
    memset(sendline, 0, 100);
    memset(recvline, 0, 100);

    /*Send 10,000 read/write operations to the server*/
    for(int i = 0; i<10000; i++){
        write(sockfd, "read\0", 5);
        read(sockfd, sendline, 100);

        write(sockfd, "write\0", 6);
        write(sockfd, recvline, 100);
    }
}
```

**server.c**

```
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>

int main()
{
    int listen_fd, comm_fd;

    struct sockaddr_in servaddr;
    listen_fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
    memset(&servaddr, 0, sizeof(servaddr));
    servaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    servaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = htons(INADDR_ANY);
    servaddr.sin_port = htons(8080);

    bind(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr *) &servaddr, sizeof(servaddr));
    listen(listen_fd, 10);
    comm_fd = accept(listen_fd, (struct sockaddr*) NULL, NULL);

    int readCount = 0;
    int writeCount = 0;

    char str[100];
    char msg[100];

    /*Server listens for client requests.*/
    while(1)
    {
        read(comm_fd, str, 10);
        if(strncmp(str, "read", 10) == 0){
            printf("Recieved a read request\n");
            write(comm_fd, msg, 100);
            readCount++;
        }else if(strncmp(str, "write", 10) == 0){
            printf("Recieved a write request\n");
            memset(str, 0, 100);
            read(comm_fd, str, 100);
            writeCount++;
        }
        memset(str, 0, 100);
        printf("read count: %d. write count: %d\n", readCount, writeCount);
    }
}
```

My suspicion is that one of the two is waiting on the other's opposite I/O operation i.e. the client wants to read, but the server also wants to read instead of writing. So I added an initial write operation, which can be `read` or `write`, that tells the server what is about to happen before the actual content is to be transmitted. But this does not resolve the block? Can someone point me in the right direction as to what causes the block, and how to resolve it?

Comment: I suggest you add error checking after each syscall, and also print the returned value of every `read` and `write` for debugging purposes, even when what they return is not an error.

Comment: Where are the client and server code stalled? Have you tried attaching a debugger to each of them? What is the output being printed to the console on each side of the connection?

Comment: You should not be sending the contents of an uninitialized buffer on the wire like that.  Your `strncmp`'s should not longer than the string you are comparing to.

Comment: I suspect what is happening is that your `str` array contains neither "read" nor "write", but rather some other value, so neither of your server's strncmp() tests succeed, and things go further south from there.  You definitely need to check the return values of your `read()` and `write()` calls and base your program's behavior on how many bytes they *actually sent* (or received) vs how many you asked them to send (or receive).

Comment: @jwdonahue Running the client through gdb, it looks like the server completes one read and one write request. But as the client to be able to send the "read" message across, but it stalls on the line of reading. Also  I `strncpy` the message "read" and "write" into a 10 byte buffer before sending, so the message size is consistent on both sides.

Comment: There are no messages or message sizes in TCP -- its just a byte stream.

Comment: @jwdonahue Running the application, I get a few successful reads and write, and I checked the received string on the server and they are "read" and "write". But something causes it to block a few operations down. Yes I do intend to save the return values of `read` and `write` in the future.

Comment: Are you aware that a TCP connection is a stream of bytes, and `read` can read any number of bytes from the stream? For instance your server's first `read` call might return "rea". This isn't "read" or "write" so it goes back and `read`s again. But the client is expecting it to `write` something. That's one possible situation where you will end up with both sides reading.

Answer (score 1):

You're not checking the return values of the `read` and `write` system calls.  ANY read or write call might read or write less data than requested, or might read more data than was written in a single write, so you need to check the return value of the calls to see how much data was actually transmitted or received.

What likely happens is your client sends a 6-byte "write" string followed by a 100-byte buffer, followed by another request.  The server reads a 10-byte buffer, getting the "write" and the first 4 bytes the buffer, then reads 100 bytes (getting the remaining 96 bytes of the buffer and the first 4 bytes of the next request).  It then tries to read another 10-byte  chunk to decode the next request, but the first 4 bytes of it have been lost...